# How to reduce cache size for radix_tree_node?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, performance, cache

Is is possible to reduce the space used for `radix_tree_node` cache in Linux without reducing overall cache size?

For example, I currently have

```
$ sudo slabtop -sc --once | awk '{ if (0 + $1  > 0) { printf "%20s: % 6d MB, active %3.0f%%\n", $8, $7 / 1024, (100*$2/$1); } }'
    ext4_inode_cache:  10387 MB, active 100%
              dentry:   2042 MB, active 100%
     radix_tree_node:    263 MB, active  90%
         buffer_head:    117 MB, active 100%
      kmalloc-rcl-64:     92 MB, active 100%
      kmalloc-rcl-96:     79 MB, active 100%
   dmaengine-unmap-2:     43 MB, active 100%
      vm_area_struct:     18 MB, active  99%
         task_struct:     13 MB, active  98%
  ext4_extent_status:     12 MB, active 100%
   ext4_groupinfo_4k:     10 MB, active 100%
         inode_cache:     10 MB, active  90%
          kmalloc-4k:      7 MB, active  99%
     kmalloc-rcl-128:      7 MB, active 100%
   kernfs_node_cache:      5 MB, active 100%
    proc_inode_cache:      5 MB, active  99%
```

So all the other caches have *at least* 98% active except the `radix_tree_node` which has only 90% active. This system is not wasting a huge amount of memory but it seems that overall cache usage would be improved if `radix_tree_node` size were reduced to get rid of non-active caches. If I run just `slabtop -sc` I get `USE 0%` for `radix_tree_node` but I assume that's just incorrect accounting.

For example, it seems that I might need to reduce `/proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure` because `dentry` caches are only 20% of the `ext4_inode_cache` with both having 100% active. For my workload, the system needs to stat a lots of directory entries.

Comment: I'm running Linux kernel version 5.3, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: I'm nowadays running kernel 5.4 and `vfs_cache_pressure` changes system behavior much more aggressively. I used to use values in range 1–10 and now I have to use values in range 100–120 to get approximately the same behavior. Nowadays `radix_tree_node` is 100% active but `buffer_head` is now using 254 MB of RAM and has only 91% active.

Comment: It seems that `dentry` and `buffer_head` are sensitive for system idling for a long time. Those get much higher active percentage when I first cause I/O load for the system and measure those again.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with this I would say that you should be running Linux kernel version 5.4 or greater and then adjust `/proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure` if needed. I would try to use as small value as possible that still doesn't cause slowdown for the system. In my experience, `vfs_cache_pressure` values in range 1–10 were good for kernel version 5.3 but kernel version 5.4 requires values close to 100 to get similar behavior.

The low value for `vfs_cache_pressure` would be good to keep more of the directory metadata in RAM so that when processes access files, the storage medium only needs to fetch the actual contents of the file. This is especially important with HDD which are slow with random access. And for the storage medium, fetching metadata for deep directory hierarchies seem like random data access because system needs to read directories on multiple levels and each directory is located in different area on the actual storage medium.

However, if you reduce `vfs_cache_pressure` too much, the system may start swapping instead of dropping directory metadata from the cache which obviously will result in poor performance, too. I think this is the single most important difference between kernel version 5.3 and 5.4. With version 5.3 you could set `vfs_cache_pressure` all the way down to `1` and system wouldn't start to swap to keep `dentries` in RAM. With kernel version 5.4 system is much more swap happy if you to much below `100`.

I think I would need to try to benchmark different combinations of `/proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure` and `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness`. I'm currently running
`vfs_cache_pressure` at 120, and `swappiness` at 80 and I'm sometimes experiencing slowdowns when a background process inspects lots of directories in the system (e.g. backup script checking for new files in the system). It appears to me that currently the system is using RAM to cache `dentries` a bit too aggressively and programs that request more memory get slowed down when RAM needs to be freed by dropping some other caches before the request can be served.